# Send email notification with response data only upon google form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

[sample dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ULMa.png)

```
`function onFormSubmit(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 4");
var lastresponse =       ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 18).getValues();
var customerEmail = lastresponse[0][10];  
var Subject = "sample updates # " + lastresponse[0][1];
var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();


var Message = "Hello Team" +  ",<br/>"
+ "Please Find Below Details :<br/>"
+ "BN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][1] + ".  </b><br/>"
+ "PN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][12] + "</b><br/>"
+ "MN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][13] + "</b><br/>"
+ "MN1 : <b>" + lastresponse[0][14] + "</b><br/>"
+ "QP = <b>" + lastresponse[0][3] + "</b><br/>"
+ "QS = <b>" + lastresponse[0][4] + "</b><br/>"
+ "FR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][5] + "</b><br/>"
+ "SLR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][6] + "</b><br/>"
+ "SLRV = <b>" + lastresponse[0][7] + "</b><br/>"
+ "FR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][8] + "</b><br/>"
+ "PR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][9] +"</b><br/>"
+ "Co : <b>" + lastresponse[0][11] + "</b><br/>"

+ "<b>please do not, reply on this    email.<b><br/>"
+ "Thank you";

GmailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, Subject, Message, { from:alias[0],htmlBody: Message,name: 'Updates'});
 } `
```

Hope you guys are doing great. I have a question which is generic but somehow I am new to google app script so unable to find it. I have a google form with 10 questions, when user submits form I receive email notification as expected but I receive all 10 questions even some of the questions unanswered by user. Is there anything I am missing that I receive data of only answered questions in email notification.

E.g if user respond to 5 questions out of 10 then I receive only those 5 questions details in email notification.

Any help on this is appreciated.

If already provided solutions then you can just tag that solution here also. Thank you.

Comment: Is this an email that you created in the onFormSubmit triggered function or is this a email that's produced by the form.  Sorry I don't use google forms much. I tend to write my own.

Comment: @Cooper I used on form submit trigger

Comment: I tried to find something like I can extract last row and remove the columns with blank and rest I can send in email notification with column title.

Comment: If you just want the data associated with the submission you don't have to get the last row of the linked sheet all of the submission data is the triggers event object.  If the event object parameter is e the e.values is an array of all of the cells in the linked sheet and e.namedValues is a key/value object.  Just do a submission with Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); and you can see the data in the JSON.  I am talking about the Spreadsheets onFormSubmit trigger not the Forms onSubmitTrigger.

Comment: @Cooper appreciate your help. I will definitely try that. Makes sense that will work too. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Cooper sorry bro I broke in between and keeps getting error which doesn’t allow me to save script. So I uploaded my code here and if you can suggest the changes needs to be made then it will be helpful.

Comment: @Cooper can you update it according to the explaination you provided about event object and everything? This once is working but if someone does not answer any of the question then it comes in as blank in email that I don’t want to see.

Comment: I could if you will supply me with an image of the linked sheet that includes the header and some data

Comment: @Cooper updated sample image, idea is basically out of five item user submits forms whenever any requirement for specific item arises. What happens now is if  one require only item 1 then in email notification I receive all 5 items with quantities in item 1 only. Is it possible that I receive only item 1 in email descriptions?

Comment: The can't be the linked sheet.  I thought they always had a time stamp on the left

Comment: @Cooper you are right but I can not share the linked sheet due to data security policy, I made a sample sheet for reference.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can save this:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 4");
  var lastresponse = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 18).getValues();
  var customerEmail = lastresponse[0][10];
  var Subject = "sample updates # " + lastresponse[0][1];
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var Message = "Hello Team" + ",<br/>" + "Please Find Below Details :<br/>" + "BN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][1] + ".  </b><br/>" + "PN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][12] + "</b><br/>" + "MN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][13] + "</b><br/>" + "MN1 : <b>" + lastresponse[0][14] + "</b><br/>" + "QP = <b>" + lastresponse[0][3] + "</b><br/>" + "QS = <b>" + lastresponse[0][4] + "</b><br/>" + "FR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][5] + "</b><br/>" + "SLR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][6] + "</b><br/>" + "SLRV = <b>" + lastresponse[0][7] + "</b><br/>" + "FR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][8] + "</b><br/>" + "PR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][9] + "</b><br/>" + "Co : <b>" + lastresponse[0][11] + "</b><br/>" + "<b>please do not, reply on this    email.<b><br/>" + "Thank you";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, Subject, Message, { from: alias[0], htmlBody: Message, name: 'Updates' });
}
```

#### Using the Event Object on a form submission

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 4");
  var vs = [e.values()];
  var customerEmail = vs[0][10];
  var Subject = "sample updates # " + vs[0][1];
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var Message = "Hello Team" + ",<br/>" 
    + "Please Find Below Details :<br/>"
    + "BN : <b>" + vs[0][1] + ".  </b><br/>"
    + "PN : <b>" + vs[0][12] + "</b><br/>"
    + "MN : <b>" + vs[0][13] + "</b><br/>"
    + "MN1 : <b>" + vs[0][14] + "</b><br/>"
    + "QP = <b>" + vs[0][3] + "</b><br/>"
    + "QS = <b>" + vs[0][4] + "</b><br/>"
    + "FR = <b>" + vs[0][5] + "</b><br/>"
    + "SLR = <b>" + vs[0][6] + "</b><br/>"
    + "SLRV = <b>" + vs[0][7] + "</b><br/>"
    + "FR = <b>" + vs[0][8] + "</b><br/>"
    + "PR = <b>" + vs[0][9] + "</b><br/>"
    + "Co : <b>" + vs[0][11] + "</b><br/>"
    + "<b>please do not, reply on this    email.<b><br/>"
    + "Thank you";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, Subject, Message, { from: alias[0], htmlBody: Message, name: 'Updates' });
}
```